# Computing Probabilities

Tags: probability, statistics

Given the joint density of two random variables $X$ and $Y$,

$f_{XY}(x,y)=2e^{-(x+y)}$ for $0<x<y$

How do I compute $P(Y<1|X<1)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P(Y<1|X<1)=\frac {P(X<1,Y<1)} {P(X<1)}=\frac {\int_0^{1} \int_x^{1}2e^{-x-y} dydx} {\int_0^{1} \int_x^{\infty}2e^{-x-y} dydx}$. I will let you evaluate the integrals.

Comment: I get 
$\frac{1-2e^{-1}+e^{-2}}{1-e^{-2}}$.

Comment: @i9-9980XE Your answer is correct.